# Capacitor Question

Tags: capacitor

If you look at [this capacitor](http://www.maplin.co.uk/radial-electrolytic-capacitors-13472) on Maplins in the specs they say 'Maximum operating temperature +85 degrees'. Does that mean anything above 85 is ok?

Comment: That means that anything BELOW 85 degrees C is acceptable.

Comment: Look up "maximum" in a dictionary.

Comment: Consider being more careful about ratings, if you think +10V on a capacitor means you can run it at 100, you could hurt/kill someone.

Answer (score 5):

If the original cap was a 105C part it is extremely likely that a 105C replacement should be used.

The use of 85C or 105C or other temperature ratings is more complex than just specifying the max operating temperature. A capacitors has a T and hours rating.

Actual lifetime at constant temperature is ~~=

Hours = Hours_Rated x 2^( (Trated-Toperating) / 10)

That is, lifetime doubles for every 10C that operating temperature is below rated temperature.  So very roughly, a 85C, 2000 hour cap will last

- 2000 hours at 85C = 3 months
- 4000 hours at 75 C
- 8000 hours at 65 C = 1 year
- 16000 hours at 55C
- 32000 hours at 45C
- 64000 hours at 35C = 8 years

his is only approximate BUT explains the apparently very high temperature ratings.

So a 105C cap is 20C higher T rated than an 85V cap (105-85 = 20) so can be expected to last about 4 x as long.

---

Free advice: When in doubt buy Panasonic caps if available :-).

Answer (score 3):

No. +85°C is the maximum temperature you can use it at. Anything lower will do fine, higher temperatures will damage the component. But regarding its lifetime, it is never wise to use components near their maximum ratings.

Answer (score 1):

No, it means that you should *not* use it above 85°C.  That is the maximum allowed temperature.

Perhaps you were confused by the `+`?  `+85°C` is the exact same thing as `85°C`.